# Bulk insert for Expo/SqlLite

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I am trying to bulk insert some data into sql-lite using Expo/React-native.

**This works fine**, when the data is a simple JSON object:

```
var data = { firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith', data: 'Test12345' }

 db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
        "INSERT INTO items (firstName, lastName, data) VALUES (?,?,?)", data,
        (txObj, result) => console.log (result),
        (txObj, error) => console.log('Error ', error)
    );
})
```

**But this fails** when it is an array of JSON objects:

```
var data = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
   data.push({ firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith', data: 'Test12345' })
}

 db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
        "INSERT INTO items (firstName, lastName, data) VALUES (?,?,?)", data,
        (txObj, result) => console.log (result),
        (txObj, error) => console.log('Error ', error)
    );
})
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through the execute calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution:

- Add (?,?,?) for each record
- Use a flat array for a bulk insert

```js
var data = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
   data.push({ firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith', data: 'Test12345' })
}

 db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
        "INSERT INTO items (firstName, lastName, data) VALUES" + Array.from({length: data.length}, () => '(?,?,?)').join(),
        data.map(d => Object.values(d)).flat(),
        (txObj, result) => console.log (result),
        (txObj, error) => console.log('Error ', error)
    );
})
```